# Tricky Decomposition

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Decompose the following polynomial:
$A=x^4(y^2+z^2) + y^4(z^2+x^2) + z^4(x^2+y^2) +2x^2 y^2 z^2 $

(by the way I'm not quite sure about the tags and the title feel free to edit them if you wish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
A = x^4(y^2+z^2) + x^2(y^4+2y^2 z^2 +z^4) +y^2z^2(y^2+z^2) \\
= (y^2+z^2)\left(x^4+(y^2+z^2)x^2 +y^2z^2\right) \\
=(y^2+z^2)(x^2+y^2)(z^2+x^2)
$$

Comment: Thanks David! Helped me much

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let $x^2=a$, let $y^2=b$ and let $z^2=c$ then we have $a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b+2abc$. I'm afraid that I just recognise this, just like how I recognise the difference of two squares, as:
$$(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)$$

Comment: Nice one!But by "I just recognise this" I believe you meant you could not find the explanatory answer to it right?If so I will try to find the answer with the explanation.Thanks!

Comment: I mean, it's very easy to expand the brackets, but very hard to, without knowing "where you are going", to factorise the polynomial. I'm not sure there's such thing as multivariate long division...

Answer (score 0):

Define the polynomial:
$$
f(a,b,c) = a^2(b + c) + b^2(c + a) + c^2(a + b) + 2abc
$$
Notice that $f$ is cyclic:
$$
f(a,b,c) = f(b,c,a) = f(c,a,b)
$$
Observe that since:
\begin{align*}
f(a,-a,c)
&= a^2(-a + c) + a^2(c + a) + 0 - 2a^2c \\
&= a^2(-a + c + c + a - 2c) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
it follows by the Factor Theorem that $a+b$ is a factor of $f$. But since $f$ is cyclic, so are $b+c$ and $a+c$. Hence, for some constant $k$, we have:
$$
a^2(b + c) + b^2(c + a) + c^2(a + b) + 2abc = k(a + b)(b + c)(a + c)
$$
By comparing the coefficient of $a^2b$, observe that $k = 1$. Hence, we conclude that:
$$
A = f(x^2, y^2, z^2) = (x^2 + y^2)(y^2 + z^2)(x^2 + y^2)
$$